# Scheduled Rate from property file

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

Hi  i like to take the scheduler value from property file , my spring version is 3.1.2 . I cant update the version of spring . fixedRateString is only available in higher version 3.2.2 . Is there any way i can get this value from property file.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000000)
```

Comment: I fear this is a "dead end" for java/annotation configuration, but you could get more lucky with "XML config" ... ?

Comment: can't do xml config .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Scheduled(cron=". . .")` expressions for task scheduling.

> If a fixed rate execution is desired, simply change the property name
> specified within the annotation. The following would be executed every
> 5 seconds measured between the successive start times of each
> invocation.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=5000)
public void doSomething() {
    // something that should execute periodically
}
```

> If simple periodic scheduling is not expressive enough, then a cron
> expression may be provided. For example, the following will only
> execute on weekdays.

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
public void doSomething() {
    // something that should execute on weekdays only
}
```

[spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

[cron-expression](https://riptutorial.com/spring/example/21209/cron-expression)